# What do 'old' and '?' mean in who commands output?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, who

Here is output of `who -u` command:

```
xenoadmin :0           2015-10-12 11:04   ?          2881 (:0)
xenoadmin pts/11       2015-10-12 11:04  old         3744 (:0)
xenoadmin pts/13       2015-10-12 12:39  old         3744 (:0)
xenoadmin pts/21       2015-10-15 19:15  old         3744 (:0)
xenoadmin pts/22       2015-10-15 12:19   .          3744 (:0)
xenoadmin pts/23       2015-10-15 12:29 00:57        3744 (:0)
xenoadmin pts/24       2015-10-15 12:30  old         3744 (:0)
xenoadmin pts/25       2015-10-15 12:30  old          447 (localhost)
xenoadmin pts/29       2015-10-21 16:52  old         3744 (:0)
```

In idle-time column, what is the meaning of 'old' and '?'. I was writing a small script which captures the ssh idle sessions and terminate them if they are idle for more than ; I am not sure how to treat these values ('old' & '?')

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is documented in the `info` page. From `info who`:

> '-u'
>
> ```
>  After the login time, print the number of hours and minutes that
>  the user has been idle. '.' means the user was active in the last
>  minute. 'old' means the user has been idle for more than 24 hours.
> ```

Additionally `?` is for X sessions, confirmed by the display number (`:0`). Expectedly there is no such thing as idle time as far as the X session is concerned hence the value `?` (unknown).